# Story book publicPath is now working after migration from v6 to v7

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook, webpack-5

on Storybook v6 we have the following code to set publicPath

```
module.exports = {
    typescript: {
        check: true,
    },

    stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.@(ts|md)x', '../src/**/*.docs.@(ts|md)x'],

    addons: [
        '@storybook/addon-links',
        '@storybook/addon-essentials',
        '@storybook/addon-docs',
        'storybook-css-modules-preset',
        '@storybook/react',
        '@storybook/addon-controls',
    ],
    webpackFinal: (config, { configType }) => {
        config.resolve.alias = {
            ...config.resolve.alias,
            '~': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
        };
         if (configType === 'PRODUCTION') {
        config.output.publicPath = '/custom-path/';
         }

        return config;
    },

    managerWebpack: (config, { configType }) => {
        if (configType === 'PRODUCTION') {
        config.output.publicPath = '/custom-path/';
        }
        return config;
    },

    framework: {
        name: '@storybook/react-webpack5',
        options: {},
    },

    docs: {
        autodocs: true,
    },
};
```

But after migration to v7 it isnt working any more, and public path is empty
we a using react in out project, so similar solution for Next.js isn fit

Public Path should work correctly